# How to implement touch effect in Android App

Tags: java, android

Good day,
I'm currently building a chat app like WhatsApp and I have this problem that I have no clue on how to solve.
Below is the screenshot of my chat screen toolbar.
Problem: No touch event/sign whenever the user clicks on the back icon and contact name.[image: My app]

I wanted something like this,
[image: WhatsApp]
[image: WhatsApp]

Comment: does it works for you??

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple android ripple effect but it works only with `API 21` and above

Create button_effect.xml in `drawable-v21`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#FFAEAE">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFAEAE" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

I was using it with red color if you want a whatsapp like effect use with translucent black colors
use it simply like this
`android:background="@drawable/button_effect"` on your layout's

EXAMPLE

```
           <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_effect" <!-- putting is as background--> 
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stackoverflow" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```